# Reading corrupted file in python

Tags: python

I've got a file, that looks like this [alt text http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/4581/crapq.png](http://img40.imageshack.us/img40/4581/crapq.png)
Now there are 5 lines shown. However running this script

```
with open('hello.txt', 'r') as hello:
    for line in hello:
        print line,
```

gives

```
num 1
ctl00$header1$Login1$txtUserName=ыют;CBШ▌
```

and that's all. How can I read entire file? TIA

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
entire_file = open('hello.txt', 'rb').read()

print 'number of \\n: %d, number of bytes %d' % (
    entire_file.count('\n'), len(entire_file))
```

Comment: @roddik: Yes, add the 'b' flag to open() to indicate you want the file to be handled as a binary file (e.g. a sequence of bytes).